# Ligatures with the JetBrains Mono font

Tags: fonts

After installing the [JetBrains Mono Font](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/) and setting it as my default face. I am wandering how to enable [Ligatures](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/#ligatures) in Emacs.

I tried a solution based on [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26824) that show how to do this with [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode), with what I think are the required modifications I am speaking about:

---

**EDIT**: [@Piquan](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/26665)'s [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/55093), suggested to me that I wasn't clear about what are the *required modifications* to the [fira-code-mode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Emacs-instructions#using-prettify-symbols), so here they are:

- Search and replace from fira-code to jetbrains-mono
- Change the code points from `#Xe100 . #Xe16f` to `#X10001 . #X1009c`
- Update the `jetbrains-ligature-mode--ligatures` constant to reflect the actual character map of the JetBrains Mono font as I see them (using [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/)).
- Since the `#X10001 . #X1009c` contains some diacritics I didn't wish to be part of the resulting `prettify-symbols-alist`, I put some `nil`s into the said constant, and introduced an `(if ...)` expression to the `jetbrains-ligature-mode--make-alist` function to ignore those `nil`s and just increment the code point.
- AFAIK, the reason the [Fira Code Ligature](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/211#issuecomment-239058632) was created for Emacs compatibility, is to be compatible with the upstream [haskling-mode](https://github.com/minad/hasklig-mode/blob/master/hasklig-mode.el) that used those code points. But since I modified the numbers to be compatible with the *JetBrains Mono* original font, this is not needed.
- I should be able to do without `jetbrains-ligature-mode--setup` function, but I figured out it shouldn't hurt to keep it (and indeed removing it as a troubleshooting step didn't help).

---

Thus the resulting code is:

```lisp
(defun jetbrains-ligature-mode--make-alist (list)
   "Generate prettify-symbols alist from LIST."
   (let ((idx -1))
     (mapcar
      (lambda (s)
        (setq idx (1+ idx))
        (if s
            (let* ((code (+ #X10001 idx))
                   (width (string-width s))
                   (prefix ())
                   (suffix '(?\s (Br . Br)))
                   (n 1))
              (while (< n width)
                (setq prefix (append prefix '(?\s (Br . Bl))))
                (setq n (1+ n)))
              (cons s (append prefix suffix (list (decode-char 'ucs code)))))))
      list)))

 (defconst jetbrains-ligature-mode--ligatures
   '("-->" "//" "/**" "/*" "*/" "<!--" ":=" "->>" "<<-" "->" "<-"
     "<=>" "==" "!=" "<=" ">=" "=:=" "!==" "&&" "||" "..." ".."
     nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil
     "|||" "///" "&&&" "===" "++" "--" "=>" "|>" "<|" "||>" "<||"
     "|||>" "<|||" ">>" "<<" nil nil "::=" "|]" "[|" "{|" "|}"
     "[<" ">]" ":?>" ":?" nil "/=" "[||]" "!!" "?:" "?." "::"
     "+++" "??" "###" "##" ":::" "####" ".?" "?=" "=!=" "<|>"
     "<:" ":<" ":>" ">:" "<>" "***" ";;" "/==" ".=" ".-" "__"
     "=/=" "<-<" "<<<" ">>>" "<=<" "<<=" "<==" "<==>" "==>" "=>>"
     ">=>" ">>=" ">>-" ">-" "<~>" "-<" "-<<" "=<<" "---" "<-|"
     "<=|" "/\\" "\\/" "|=>" "|~>" "<~~" "<~" "~~" "~~>" "~>"
     "<$>" "<$" "$>" "<+>" "<+" "+>" "<*>" "<*" "*>" "</>" "</" "/>"
     "<->" "..<" "~=" "~-" "-~" "~@" "^=" "-|" "_|_" "|-" "||-"
     "|=" "||=" "#{" "#[" "]#" "#(" "#?" "#_" "#_(" "#:" "#!" "#="
     "&="))

(defvar jetbrains-ligature-mode--old-prettify-alist)

(defun jetbrains-ligature-mode--enable ()
    "Enable JetBrains Mono ligatures in current buffer."
    (setq-local jetbrains-ligature-mode--old-prettify-alist prettify-symbols-alist)
       (setq-local prettify-symbols-alist (append (jetbrains-ligature-mode--make-alist jetbrains-ligature-mode--ligatures) jetbrains-ligature-mode--old-prettify-alist))
       (prettify-symbols-mode t))

(defun jetbrains-ligature-mode--disable ()
    "Disable JetBrains Mono ligatures in current buffer."
    (setq-local prettify-symbols-alist jetbrains-ligature-mode--old-prettify-alist)
    (prettify-symbols-mode -1))

(define-minor-mode jetbrains-ligature-mode
    "JetBrains Mono ligatures minor mode"
    :lighter " JetBrains Mono"
    (setq-local prettify-symbols-unprettify-at-point 'right-edge)
    (if jetbrains-ligature-mode
        (jetbrains-ligature-mode--enable)
      (jetbrains-ligature-mode--disable)))

(defun jetbrains-ligature-mode--setup ()
    "Setup JetBrains Mono Symbols"
    (set-fontset-font t '(#X10001 . #X1009c) "JetBrains Mono"))

(provide 'jetbrains-ligature-mode)
```

However the best I got so far is that the sequence is replaced with an empty space (although with the correct length).

What am I missing?

---

I am using Emacs 26.3 (from [Kevin Kelley's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kelleyk/+archive/ubuntu/emacs)) on Kubuntu 18.04

Comment: Perhaps this will be improved with the font rendering and text shaping improvements coming to emacs 27. Perhaps it won’t.

Comment: I attempted a similar thing, and ran into the same problem you did. I’m thinking it might be because the Unicode value in the JetBrains Mono font is -1 (right click -> glyph info) for the ligatures. In the Fira Code Symbol font the values are their indexes in the font. My guess is the prettify doesn’t see the ligatures as valid characters because of this, but editors like VS Code with native ligature support don’t need a valid value. I haven’t had a chance yet to test this theory, but if I get the chance before you do I’ll update here.

Answer (score 6):

You want to do this with composition rules, not with prettify-symbols. Try this instead:

```lisp
(defconst jetbrains-ligature-mode--ligatures
   '("-->" "//" "/**" "/*" "*/" "<!--" ":=" "->>" "<<-" "->" "<-"
     "<=>" "==" "!=" "<=" ">=" "=:=" "!==" "&&" "||" "..." ".."
     "|||" "///" "&&&" "===" "++" "--" "=>" "|>" "<|" "||>" "<||"
     "|||>" "<|||" ">>" "<<" "::=" "|]" "[|" "{|" "|}"
     "[<" ">]" ":?>" ":?" "/=" "[||]" "!!" "?:" "?." "::"
     "+++" "??" "###" "##" ":::" "####" ".?" "?=" "=!=" "<|>"
     "<:" ":<" ":>" ">:" "<>" "***" ";;" "/==" ".=" ".-" "__"
     "=/=" "<-<" "<<<" ">>>" "<=<" "<<=" "<==" "<==>" "==>" "=>>"
     ">=>" ">>=" ">>-" ">-" "<~>" "-<" "-<<" "=<<" "---" "<-|"
     "<=|" "/\\" "\\/" "|=>" "|~>" "<~~" "<~" "~~" "~~>" "~>"
     "<$>" "<$" "$>" "<+>" "<+" "+>" "<*>" "<*" "*>" "</>" "</" "/>"
     "<->" "..<" "~=" "~-" "-~" "~@" "^=" "-|" "_|_" "|-" "||-"
     "|=" "||=" "#{" "#[" "]#" "#(" "#?" "#_" "#_(" "#:" "#!" "#="
     "&="))

(sort jetbrains-ligature-mode--ligatures (lambda (x y) (> (length x) (length y))))

(dolist (pat jetbrains-ligature-mode--ligatures)
  (set-char-table-range composition-function-table
                      (aref pat 0)
                      (nconc (char-table-range composition-function-table (aref pat 0))
                             (list (vector (regexp-quote pat)
                                           0
                                    'compose-gstring-for-graphic)))))
```

In order to improve the performance of redisplay, you could take all
the ligature patterns that start with the same character, and use
`regexp-opt` to produce one regular expression matching all of them, ie use

```lisp
(regexp-opt '("###" "## "####" "#{" "#[" "#(" "#?" "#_" "#_(" "#:" "#!" "#="))
```

as the pattern for `#`.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for! Your code works perfectly for me, as of Emacs 26.3.

Comment: This worked great for me until I typed four asterisks in a row (org-mode) and emacs froze solid...

Comment: Using which version of emacs? (presumably from 'emacs -Q'). If you still get this in emacs-27, please `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: The order in which the ligatures appear is important for all of them to work properly, In other words, this _kinda_ works, but for example `+++` renders as `++` ligature followed by a  `+`. But making the `+++` ligature appear before the `++` ligature minor fixes this issue for me.

Comment: That's a good suggestion (but I removed your hash-quoting of the lambda, it's not necessary)

Comment: This approach rises an error in Doom Emacs "Attempt to shape unibyte text".

Answer (score 0):

Per the [upstream Fira Code instructions](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Emacs-instructions#using-prettify-symbols), you have to install the Fira Code Symbol font to use the mechanism being used here.  The [Fira Code Symbol font](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/211#issuecomment-239058632) is a separate font that has the Fira Code ligatures, but puts them as regular characters in the font so that Emacs can access them.  (You may note that the original Fira Code example referred to `"Fira Code Symbol"` rather than `"Fira Code"` in the `set-fontset-font` call.)  Without that font, this mechanism won't work.

Unfortunately, I don't know of an analogous symbol font for JetBrains Mono yet, so this solution wouldn't apply.  Of course, JetBrains Mono is quite new, so somebody may make one soon!

If somebody does create one, you'll need to make sure that the constant base that you use (`#X10001` in your post), and the order of the elements of `jetbrains-ligature-mode--ligatures`, both match the (theoretical future) JetBrains Mono Symbol font.

Comment: #Piquan, thanks for your answer. I think our understanding of the `fira-code-mode` is more or less similar. I updated my question to clarify what I changed in it to get to my code. Does this look sensible, or does the range `#Xe100 . #Xe16f` is somewhat more *real* from `#X10001 . #X1009c` in this context?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I haven't looked at the font in FontForge, but I have in other tools.  I don't understand the tools closely, but as far as I can tell, the ligatures in JetBrains Mono have glyph values (like all glyphs must), but those aren't assigned to any individual Unicode codepoints.  So in other words, there's not a single Unicode character that Emacs could print that would cause that ligature to be printed.  The numbers computed in jetbrains-ligature-mode--make-alist are supposed to correspond to Unicode codepoints, not glyph numbers.